# Can you identify this cheap single speed bike?

Tags: identify-this-bike

Is it worth $250?

Seller says he bought it for $350 from a bike shop.
It's got no visible decals from the pictures...

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What its worth is highly market and person specific. Try to look for a serial number and see if any of the components are marked so you can assess their value, but I suspect its just a basic single speed frame with base components.

Comment: As a rough guide I would never pay more than 50% of rack rate for a second hand bike, but this is country and market (as in type and value of bike) dependent.

Comment: Probably not worth $250, but it appears to be a step above the cheapest department store  bikes.  It should be more a question of what it's worth to you -- does it suit you needs and budget?

Comment: You can also ask the guy where he bought it and check the shop (presumably its not too far away).

Comment: To follow on from @Batman's comment, even if you can't visit the shop, if seller says they bought it from a shop, they should have some documentation that came with the bike. This will not only tell you what the bike is, it would also be a pretty good indicator that it hasn't been stolen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those wheels are worn.  That would need to be a $700 bike new to be worth $250 in that condition.

Pictures don't show detail on the items like brakes, bb, crank, wheel, hub, and chainring that would give a clue. If you are not finding mid range name brand components that bike is not worth $250.

A lowest end bike is under $100.  This is picture of $300 bike new.  Assume that is a low end bike until you have evidence it is not. 
[image]